# Hover and Click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link with an hover effect.
When you hover it, the text become red and underlined.
When you click it, the text stay red and underlined.

My problem is that once you clicked on the link, the hover effect still play... But I do not want this effect.

(I don't use toggle, because it's not supported by the last Jquery : 1.9)

**[HERE'S MY JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnwb3vLf/4/)**

```
$("h1").addClass("clicked")

$('h1').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {

        $("span").animate({"width": "145px"}, 300);
    $("h1").css({"color": "red"}, 300);


        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {

        $("span").animate({"width": "0"}, 300);
    $("h1").css({"color": "black"}, 300);

        $(this).addClass("clicked");

    }
}); 


$('h1').hover(function() {

    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {

        $("span").stop().animate({"width": "145px"}, 300);
    $("h1").css({"color": "red"}, 300);
        $(this).removeClass("clicked")
    } else {

        $("span").stop().animate({"width": "0"}, 300);
    $("h1").css({"color": "black"}, 300);

        $(this).addClass("clicked");

    }
});
```

Comment: I modified your fiddle see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lnwb3vLf/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand your question you want to:

- Hover to make it red and underline
- Click to make it always red and underlined
- Click again to enable hover red again

Following part of your code needed changes. `hover` can take two functions one for `onmouseover` other for `onmouseleave` and it becomes like:

```
$('h1').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    return;
  }

  $("span").stop().animate({
    "width": "145px"
  }, 300);
  $("h1").css({
    "color": "red"
  }, 300);
}, function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    return;
  }
  $("span").stop().animate({
    "width": "0"
  }, 300);
  $("h1").css({
    "color": "black"
  }, 300);


});
```

I modified your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4heds7q/) assuming above points. If you move mouse over, it gets red; take away mouse, goes black, and click to make it always red.

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind events with the unbind jQuery method.

```
$('h1').click(function() {
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, in this decade it's `off()`, to be used with the proper `on()`.

Answer (score 1):

I update your fiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnwb3vLf/9/)

use this query in click function

```
$(this).off('hover');
```

Answer (score 1):

**easiest way with css and jquery**

```js
$('h1').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
       $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
       $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }
});
```

```css
span {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red; 
  height: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  left:10px;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}
h1{
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
h1:hover{
  color: red;
}
h1:hover span{
  width: 145px;
  color: red; 
}
h1.clicked{
  color: red;
}
h1.clicked span{
  width: 145px;
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<h1>
MY TEXT <span></span>
</h1>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```